# How to do Many To Many relationship in Ef Core using Fluent API?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to create a many to many relation in the Fluent API with Ef Core 6 but i am having trouble understanding how to do so.

I've looked around here in stackoverflow but couldn't understand this relation and how to reproduce it in my code.

I have a table in my SQL database called People:

**People.cs:**

```cs
 public class People : PeopleBase
    {
        public People()
        {
            RegistrationList = new HashSet<Registration>();
        }

        public virtual ICollection<Registration> RegistrationList { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }

        public virtual ActivityGroup ActivityGroup { get; set; }
    }
```

**PeopleBase.cs:**

```cs
 public abstract class PeopleBase: ModelBase
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid PeopleId { get; set; }

        public Guid? UserId { get; set; }

        public Guid? ActivityGroupId { get; set; }

        public string Code { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Surname { get; set; }

        public PeopleActiveType Active { get; set; }
    }
```

And then i have another table called ActivityGroup:

**ActivityGroup.cs:**

```cs
public class ActivityGroup : ActivityGroupBase
    {
        public ActivityGroup()
        {
            PeopleList = new HashSet<People>();
            ActivityList = new HashSet<Activity>();
        }

        public ICollection<People> PeopleList { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Activity> ActivityList { get; set; }
    }
```

**ActivityGroupBase.cs:**

```cs
public abstract class ActivityGroupBase : ModelBase
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid ActivityGroupId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public StatusRecord Status { get; set; }
    }
```

How would i do the mapping in the `modelBuilder` given that:

- `ActivityGroupId` is the foreing key in the `People` database, pointing to the other table
- One `PeopleId` can have multiple (many) `ActivityGroupId`
- One `ActivityGroupId` can be assigned to multiple people.

**What i've done so far:**

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<People>()
   .HasOne(x => x.ActivityGroup)
   .WithMany(x => x.PeopleList)
   .HasForeignKey(x => x.ActivityGroupId);
```

Wouldn't i have to do this instead?

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<People>()
   .Hasmany(x => x.ActivityGroupList) //this is a ICollection<ActivityGroup> inside People class
   .WithMany(x => x.PeopleList)
   .HasForeignKey(x => x.ActivityGroupId); // this is not recognized by Ef Core
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What you have described here is One To Many relationship. ActivityGroup has many people while people has one activityGroup and that means its a one to many relation. where is ICollection<ActivityGroup> in people class?

Comment: The thing is that one PeopleId can have multiple ActivityGroupId? But i am guessing that i do not fully undestrand how this works even in SQL.

Comment: My guess would be that is not possbile to asign a foreing key to one table having multiple elements

Comment: take a look at this article:   https://database.guide/database-relationships-explained/ .      It explains relationships in database clearly. in many to many relationship you dont need foreignkey for ether of the tables

Comment: Okay i understand now how this works, i am still having problems... what i did was creating another table with two columns `PeopleId` and `ActivityGroupId` (they are Primary Keys as well as Foreign Keys)

Comment: I understand that this is difficult for you to solve since there is lack of context so i'll thank you for the repsonses cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There are two main approaches for [many-to-many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many) relationships - with implicit junction table:

```
public class People : PeopleBase
{
   // ...
   public virtual List<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
}

public class Activity // : ...
{
   // ...
   public virtual List<People> PeopleList { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<People>()
   .HasMany(x => x.Activities)
   .WithMany(x => x.PeopleList);
```

Or with [explicit one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#indirect-many-to-many-relationships):

```
public class People
{
  // ...
  public ICollection<PeopleActivity> PeopleActivities { get; set; }
}

public class Activity
{
  // ...
  public virtual ICollection<PeopleActivity> PeopleActivities { get; set; }
}

public class PeopleActivity
{
   public Guid ActivityId { get; set; }
   public Guid PeopleId { get; set; }
   public Activity Activity { get; set; }
   public People People { get; set; }
}
```

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PeopleActivity>()  
   .HasOne(pt => pt.People)           
   .WithMany(t => t.PeopleActivities) 
   .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.PeopleId);
```

Also maybe it worth changing entity name from `People` to `Person` (you can change table name with `.ToTable("People")` call)?

Comment: Okay but how would i tell EF about the foreign key `ActivityGroupId` in the `Pearson` table

Comment: @ludodev69 if _"One `People` can have multiple (many) `ActivityGroup`"_ then there should be no `ActivityGroupId` on `People` (at least for goal of having many-to-many relation)